# Local files combination text display

Tags: feeds

I'm working on a site (new to Drupal) that is for an organization with several official rules documents (for different departments and events). I would like to store these documents locally and have individual pages not link to them but display their content in text fields. These pages will have other content and various combinations of the rules. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem. I would like to minimize Content Types and feeds dosen't seem quite set up for this.

For instance, if I have two documents on my computer and I have two pages on my site that each have their own content (just some text and a title) but also the first document has the text from the first document displayed and the second page has the first and second documents' text. Also, I would like to easily add more pages, document, and combinations.

Is there a way (I was thinking with feeds perhaps something else would work) to have a field that I could assign to content types so that the field is filled with text from a local file? Or is there something else that would get the job done?
Thanks!

Comment: The only project I know of that even comes close to what you want has no releases yet. Look at the [Text Extract](http://drupal.org/project/text_extract) project which is an Apache Tika integration. All I can suggest is to contact the project maintainer and see where he is in the development.